# Python Basics: Convert np.array to

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following np.array: `{0: array([[254, 426],...54, 426]])}`

and would like this as desired output: `[(444, 703), (623, 543), (691, 177), (581, 26), (482, 42)]`

How can I do this? I need the variable to be set like in the desired output.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the first thing you have is dict, not array. To get array you need call `var[0]` where var is name of variable with dict.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: Convert them to... ? List of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments that is not an array but a dictionary. can get list of tuples buy doing this:

```
list(map(tuple, dict[0]))
```

where dict is your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(f'NumPy Array:\n{arr}')

list1 = arr.tolist()
print(f'List: {list1}')
```